# Validating A Questionnaire Form?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, dom-events

My knowledge of JS is very limited and i need help in validating this form so its like the previous questionnaire they had which you can see on [this URL](http://spillcraft.com/test.html)

Is it best to use a jQuery plugin or Javascript? I'm trying to get it so when you select one checkbox per question you have a score appearing in bottom right hand corner and if you get the answer right the score increments by 1.

Probably the biggest thing I have done in JS so far. Any pointers or suggestions? Advice would be appreciated.

Current new form [here](http://spillcraft.flyingatom.everycity.co.uk/are-you-spill-safe/are-you-spill-safe.aspx).

Comment: Please don't use shortened URLs, we don't charge per letter here.

Comment: Please attempt to do some research before posting here. This question has been asked countless times before. A quick google search for "javascript form validation" pulls up hundreds of examples that do what you want. For example, [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've managed to sort this problem out -  wrote an on click function and like created variables for the score and incremented this on click if the answer is correct which was then spanned in to a div that was setup.

Took ages to do but got there in the end :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use jQuery or server side validation. Also, change your check boxes to groups of radio buttons, that way it's only possible to select one because of the way radio buttons work.

Comment: it has to be checkboxes for this form. Otherwise i would have used radio buttons.

Comment: Oh. I don't know why that is, but I guess you have a good reason.